# ros_lib Install error

Tags: ros, ros-lib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys here is  a error installing ros_lib any help will appreciated. I'm new with Ros and Ubuntu.

@administrator:/home$ rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py  /sketchbook/libraries/
Exporting to /sketchbook/libraries
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/hydro/share/rosserial_arduino/make_libraries.py", line 87, in 
shutil.copytree(rosserial_arduino_dir+"/src/ros_lib", path+"/ros_lib")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 175, in copytree
os.makedirs(dst)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
makedirs(head, mode)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
makedirs(head, mode)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/sketchbook'

Ubuntu 12.04
ros-hydro

I also try sudo su and them rosrun and here is the error:

juanquy@administrator:/home$ sudo su
[sudo] password for juanquy:
root@administrator:/home# rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py /home/sketchbook/librariesrosrun: command not found

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143546/ros_lib-install-error/) by [juanquy](https://answers.ros.org/users/13741/juanquy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2014-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should not rosrun things as root. Instead, either make sure you have write permissions to the /sketchbook/libraries folder, or use a location in in your home, maybe `~/sketchbook/libraries`?

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [juanquy](https://answers.ros.org/users/13741/juanquy/) on 2014-04-02**:
Thank you, I just used the root of my home and them cp to /sketchbook/libraries and done.
Thank you again

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-03**:
If your problem is solved, please mark an answer as accepted to indicate this to others. Thanks.